# What is the correct way to convert an Angular 1 provider to Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

There are lot of documentation and examples on how to convert Angular 1 services and factories to Angular2 but I couldnt find anything on how to convert a ng1 provider to something equivalent in ng2.

Example provider

```
function AlertService () {
    this.toast = false;

    this.$get = getService;

    this.showAsToast = function(isToast) {
        this.toast = isToast;
    };

    getService.$inject = ['$timeout', '$sce'];

    function getService ($timeout, $sce) {
        var toast = this.toast,
            alertId = 0, // unique id for each alert. Starts from 0.
            alerts = []

        return {
            factory: factory,
            add: addAlert
        };

        function factory(alertOptions) {
            var alert = {
                type: alertOptions.type,
                msg: $sce.trustAsHtml(alertOptions.msg),
                id: alertOptions.alertId,
                toast: alertOptions.toast
            };
            alerts.push(alert);

            return alert;
        }

        function addAlert(alertOptions) {
            alertOptions.alertId = alertId++;
            var alert = this.factory(alertOptions);

            return alert;
        }

    }


}

angular
  .module('angularApp', [])
  .provider('AlertService', AlertService);
```

What would be the correct equivalent for this in Angular 2?

Comment: What would make one equivalent better than the next?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure. I couldn't find anything on the Internet for this, so for me frankly an equivalent that does the job and follows ng2 guideline would be good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally we figured it out thanks to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3664#issuecomment-251902173

Here is the Service in NG2

```
import {Injectable, Sanitizer, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AlertService {

    private alertId: number;
    private alerts: any[];

    constructor(private sanitizer: Sanitizer, private toast: boolean) {
        this.alertId = 0; // unique id for each alert. Starts from 0.
        this.alerts = [];
    }

    factory(alertOptions): any {
        var alert = {
            type: alertOptions.type,
            msg: this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, alertOptions.msg),
            id: alertOptions.alertId,
            toast: alertOptions.toast
        };
        this.alerts.push(alert);
        return alert;
    }

    addAlert(alertOptions, extAlerts): any {
        alertOptions.alertId = this.alertId++;
        var alert = this.factory(alertOptions);
        return alert;
    }

    isToast(): boolean {
        return this.toast;
    }
}
```

and here is the provider for the service

```
import { Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertService } from './alert.service';

export function alertServiceProvider(toast?: boolean) {
    // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
    let isToast = toast ? toast : false;
    return {
        provide: AlertService,
        useFactory: (sanitizer: Sanitizer) => new AlertService(sanitizer, isToast),
        deps: [Sanitizer]
    }
}
```

Now you need to call the `alertServiceProvider` method in the provider declaration of your module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
        alertServiceProvider()
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class SharedCommonModule {}
```

The code is part of the JHipster project and you can browse actual templates [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/angular-2/generators/client-2/templates/src/main/webapp/app/shared/alert)

Comment: Does thhis work with [AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)?

Comment: Havent tested that yet

Comment: I think you need to reorganize a bit, the basic approach should still work. Just move the `{provide: ...}` part directly to `@NgModule(providers: [])` (out of of `function alertServiceProvider()`). https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts